# Azure Monitor alert is sending false failure email notifications of failure count of 1 for Functions app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a Functions app where I've configured signal logic to send me an alert whenever a failure greater than or equal to one has occurred in my application. I have been getting emails everyday saying my Azure Monitor alert was triggered followed by an email later saying that the failure was resolved. I know that my app didn't fail because I checked in Application Insights. For instance, I did not have a failure today, but did have a failures the prior 2 days:
[image: Azure Function Failures]

However, I did receive a failure email today. If I go to configure the signal logic where I set a static threshold of failure count greater than or equal to 1 it shows this:
[image: failure count]

Why is it showing a failure for today, when I know that isn't true from the Application Insights logs? Also, if I change the signal logic to look at total failures instead of count of failures, it looks correct:
[image]

I've decided to use the total failures metric instead, but it seems that the count functionality is broken.

Edit:
Additional screenshot:
[image: Configure signal logic]

Comment: May I know which signal did you choose for the alert ? And could you please share a screenshot of the "Configure signal logic" page ?

Comment: Hey @HuryShen, I chose the "Failures" signal. The second and third image are both from the "Configure signal logic" page, but I just added a screenshot of the entire page.

Comment: I think it is difficult for us to analyze the cause of the problem based on the available information. You can raise a support ticket on azure portal by following the steps on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). Azure support team will help you on it.

Comment: @JohnT, what's the type of your function? time trigger or other triggers?

Comment: @IvanYang it's a Timer Trigger

Comment: @JohnT, then what's the `cron` expression?

Comment: @IvanYang ```0 0 12 * * *```

Comment: @JohnT, please try to use the following method, and see if you can see this behavior again. I used it many times, no such behavior.

Comment: @JohnT, I want to know if you have solved the issue or not with the new solution?

Comment: in this scenario, can we get the alerts based on the percentage of failures within a time frame says in 20 minutes, than the just calculation by counts

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use `Custom log search` as the `signal` if you have already connected your function app with Application insights(I'd like to use this kind of signal, and don't see such behavior like yours).

The steps as below:

**Step 1:** For signal, please select `Custom log search`. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

**Step 2:** When the azure function times out, it will throw an error and the error type is `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException`, so you can use the query below to check if it times out or not:

```
exceptions 
| where type == "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException"
```

Put the above query in the "Search query" field, and configure other settings as per your need. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

Then configure other settings like action group etc. Please let me know if you still have such issue.

One thing should be noted: Some kinds of triggers support [retry logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages#retry-support), like blogtrigger. So if it reties, you can also receive the alert email. But you can disable the retry logic as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings).